# func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact])

Tags: swift, cncontact

By using this function

```
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact])
```

: - The user is able to select multiple contacts at the same time and return to our app at the end
but I want to next time when a picker is open the previously selected contacts should be check marked...

Comment: did you find a solution? because that's exactly what I want to have :)

Answer (score 0):

The “selected" state flag isn't available on the `CNContact` object and thus isn't available for display in the picker view controller.

**It seems to me that if you want to add that state into your app you're going to need to get creative with your own solution. :p**